# Ingest JSON files into SOLR through Flume

Tags: json, solr, bigdata, cloudera, flume

I would like to use Flume to ingest JSON files into SOLR and I would like to know which is the best way to do that.
For the moment, the only way that works for me is to use a JSONHandler in Flume but the json events need to have a specific format (headers, body). The JSON events I want to ingest have nested data and do not have a (headers, body) format. 
Please find below my Flume source configuration (HTTP source, memory channel and solr sink).

```
c_aggregator_poc.sources  = c_analytics-httpsource1-poc
c_aggregator_poc.channels = c_analytics-memorychannel1-poc
c_aggregator_poc.sinks    = c_analytics-solrsink1-poc


c_aggregator_poc.sources.c_analytics-httpsource1-poc.type     = http
c_aggregator_poc.sources.c_analytics-httpsource1-poc.handler     = org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler
c_aggregator_poc.sources.c_analytics-httpsource1-poc.port     = 9049

c_aggregator_poc.sources.c_analytics-httpsource1-poc.channels = c_analytics-memorychannel1-poc

c_aggregator_poc.channels.c_analytics-memorychannel1-poc.type   = memory
c_aggregator_poc.channels.c_analytics-memorychannel1-poc.capacity   = 10000
c_aggregator_poc.channels.c_analytics-memorychannel1-poc.transactionCapacity   = 1000


c_aggregator_poc.sinks.c_analytics-solrsink1-poc.type         = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSolrSink
c_aggregator_poc.sinks.c_analytics-solrsink1-poc.channel      = c_analytics-memorychannel1-poc
c_aggregator_poc.sinks.c_analytics-solrsink1-poc.morphlineFile   = morphlines.conf
c_aggregator_poc.sinks.c_analytics-solrsink1-poc.morphlineId = morphlineC_analytics
```

Another idea would be to write a custom JSONHandler but I wonder if that does not exist yet (I didn't find a good example yet).
An option would be to do it in Morphlines. I saw there is a readJson function but I did not used it yet.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So when adding json file, how is your document defined in solr. Because that is how they are searched.

Comment: My json file has a nested structure. I want to retrive only some information from the file (flatten). Fields are not nested in Solr.

Comment: did you succeed? i have the same problem, but in my case i did wrap my http json message with header and body but i can't read the extract body using extractJsonPaths after readJson (only the header works)